# Python ASCII 16 and 17 symbol

Tags: python, printing, ascii

Is it possible to print ASCII 16 (DLE) symbol in python? What is the simplest way to implement this symbol to clock program?

Answer (score 0):

This prints ASCII 16 character (16 = 0x10 in hexadecimal)

```
print ("\x10")
```

This prints ASCII 17 character (17 = 0x11 in hexadecimal)

```
print ("\x11")
```

Comment: I didn't get print any character.

Comment: @MalumPhobos your console or the font it uses apparently doesn't support those characters.  Works fine for me in Idle on Windows, but for some reason stackoverflow won't let me paste the characters into a comment.

Comment: @MalumPhobos P.S. technically 16 and 17 in ASCII are control characters that are not expected to print.  Unicode appears to be the same so I'm not sure why I'm seeing anything.

Comment: You are seeing things, because those control chars make no sense to the device (most likely a virtual device, like a terminal emulator), so some decide to print something instead (often a white square for example). Control char should not print something but tell the device to do something. One well known is ``\x0A`` that tells the device to change line (aka ``\n``), or ``\x0D`` aka ``\r`` that tells the device to go back to the beginning of the line. That makes more sense with a physical device, but keep in mind that this dates back to the time when there was no screen but actual printers.

Comment: So, printable chars just made the printer (besides, imagine a remote controlled typewriter, not a laser printer) type something. When non-printable chars made it do something, like feed the paper 1 line down, or make the printhead return to the beginning. Or ring a bell (``\x07``), which still works on some terminal. Or stop interpreting future chars as ASCII code until further notice (``\x10``) or turn on flow control (``\x11``).

Comment: Some of those code make sense even for a virtual terminal emulator, like ``\n``, ``\r``. Some don't.

Comment: But none of them are associated with a printable symbol. Some fonts contain a symbol, just in case the software decide to print something. For example, the 3 letters "DLE" superposed in diagonal for ``\x11``. But you can't count on it. What any device or virtual device or any software is supposed to do with those chars is up to them

Comment: Th OP wrote "for clock program".  Maybe he wants to print characters 16 and 17 from codepage 437 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).  If my guess is correct, then theses correspond to unicode codepoints 25BA and 25C4; so the answer is `print("\u25Ba")` and `print("\u25C4")`.  If this seems to be correct, then I will edit my answer.